# Parse User Column vs. ACL

Tags: parse-platform

I'm using the Parse iOS SDK, and I want to restrict records in Parse to be only for a specific user. Do I need a `user` column to track this, or will the `ACL` column provide all the functionality I will need?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: ACL can specify permissions for a user or a role, so it has what you need.  But you might be able to do all that you need with just class level permissions.

Comment: read the docs on ACL .. use the dashboard and check ACL col on your _User class.  ACL {READ: $self, WRITE: $self} will lock it down to just that user